# Conditional Formatting Simplification

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two questions about conditional formatting.
1 issue I have the output isn't correct, the 2nd I want to know if there just an easier way to accomplish the same output.

Question_1:

I am currently comparing two numbers (A1, A2)and I have the difference in a third cell (A3)
I want to change Change the colour of Cell A1 based on the value of A3.

This is what I have and it is all coming up either green or red.

```
AND(A3>5.01,A3<-10.01)  Colour == Amber

A3<-10.01               Colour == Red

AND(A3=0,A3>-5)         Colour == Green

A3 >0                   Colour == Blue
```

Question_2

I have 7 possible grades and all grades have a point 1,2 and 3.
So A1,A2,A3 ETC

I want to colour the current grade to see if it is above or below their predicted grade. My issue is that as there are 21 possibilities I am creating conditional formatting for each possibility against each possibility. Both for if it is above and below. Below is a snippet just for the A1,A2,A3 to see if it is above the predicted grade.

Can anyone think of anything quicker to accomplish this?

TIA!

```
=IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="A2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="A3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="B1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="B2"),TRUE,IF(AND(U4="A1",S4="B3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="C1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="C2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="C3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="D1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="D2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="D3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="E1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="E2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="E3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="F1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="F2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="F3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="G1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="G2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="G3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="F"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A1",U4="U"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="A3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="B1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="B2"),TRUE,IF(AND(U4="A2",S4="B3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="C1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="C2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="C3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="D1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="D2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="D3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="E1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="E2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="E3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="F1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="F2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="F3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="G1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="G2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="G3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="F"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A2",U4="U"),TRUE,FALSE)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

=IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="B1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="B2"),TRUE,IF(AND(s4="A3",u4="B3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="C1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="C2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="C3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="D1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="D2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="D3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="E1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="E2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="E3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="F1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="F2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="F3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="G1"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="G2"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="G3"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="F"),TRUE,IF(AND(S4="A3",U4="U"),
```

Comment: `AND(A3>5.01,A3<-10.01)` can never be true, I think you mean `OR`, don't you? The value can never be both >5 and less than -10 at the same time. Another suggestion: at exactly the cutoff value 10.01  make sure one of the formulas is true; I would use `<=` for one of them and `>` for the other.

Comment: Or maybe you meant `AND(A3>=-10.01,A3<= 5.01)`?

Comment: I means for any number between -5 and -10 then ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: I think you simply have an error in the formulas and the minus sign is missing in the first one on the 5. Do this instead:

```
AND(A3>=-10.01,A3<=-5.01)  Colour == Amber

A3<-10.01               Colour == Red

AND(A3<=0,A3>-5.01)         Colour == Green

A3 >0                   Colour == Blue
```

I also adjusted the formulas to use >= and < to make sure there are no values like -5.01 that "slip through the cracks" when the value is exactly -5.01 or -10.01 and match none of the conditions.

Question 2:

You could make a table like this which sorts the grades in increasing order:

```
|Grade   |
|========|
| A1     |
| A2     |
| A3     |
| B1     |
```

etc.   Then use the `MATCH` function to retrieve the order in the list and simply subtract, i.e.:

```
=MATCH(S4,$B$5:$B$8,0)-MATCH(U4,$B$5:$B$8,0)
```

where `$B$5:$B$8` is a reference to the list of grades in ascending order.

Or if you want the boolean TRUE or FALSE you can compare the subtraction to 0:

```
=(MATCH(S4,$B$5:$B$8,0)-MATCH(U4,$B$5:$B$8,0))>0
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try the table method see if it makes my life any easier. Thank you.

Comment: The table method works perfectly! Thanks. However, the first one still isn't working for me. I appreciate the fact you added the "=" I completely forgot to do this!  No matter what I do the negative numbers do not seem to work correctly.

Comment: Could you post again the exact formulas you're using now?

Comment: Sorry for commenting a lot later -                                                                                                                                                  =AND(F11<=0,F11< =-5)                           ( Between 0 and -5)                                                       =AND(F11>-5.01,F11>=-10)                      (Between -5.01 and -10)                                                            =F11<-10.01                                               ( over -10)                                                  =F11 >0

Comment: You've still got a few of the > signs wrong. Between 0 and -5 should be >=-5, not <=, Between -5.01 and -10 should be <-5, not > -5.

Comment: Sorry! Thought I did two days ago. Seemed I just  didn’t! Done now though

Comment: And thanks will try those changes later.